# Distribution of random variables - Calculations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let our sample space be $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3\}^2$ with the individual probabilities $P(\{w\})$ for $w = (w_1, w_2) \in \Omega$ given by:
>
> [image: Table]
>
> What is the minimal range space $X(\Omega)$ for the following random variables?
>
> (i) $X(w) = w_1$
>
> (ii) $X(w) = \dfrac{w_1}{w_2}$
>
> (iii) $X(w) = max\{w_1, w_2\} - min\{w_1, w_2\}$
>
> (iv) $X(w) = \text{ } \mid \{w_1, w_2\} \mid$

Here's what I have:

(i) $X(\Omega) = \{1, 2, 3\}.$

(ii) $X(\Omega) =\{1, \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{3}, 2, \dfrac{2}{3}, 3, \dfrac{3}{2}\}.$

(iii) $X(\Omega) = \{1, 2\}.$ -> I haven't included $0$ because tuples like $(1, 1)$, where $w_1 = w_2$ have no $max$ or $min$(?)

(iv) $X(\Omega) = \{2\}.$

Can someone please check my answers and let me know if I made any mistakes? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to be more careful in the case when $w_1 = w_2$: In (iii): $\max\{w_1, w_2\} = \min\{w_1, w_2\} = w_1$ so $X(\omega) = 0$. And in (iv): $|\{w_1,w_2\}| = |\{w_1\}| = 1$. In both cases you're missing a value in $X(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Sam Aaah, I see. Thank you!